# UIDocumentInteractionController presentation style

Tags: ios, ipad, popover, uiactionsheet, uidocumentinteraction

I am developing an app for iPad. I am able to show `UIDocumentInteractionController` for an item to open in other app successfully. But I have to change the presentation style of my `UIDocumentInteractionController`. It's opening in pop over, I want it to be like action sheet with cancel button.

Thanks in advance.